# Where can I find documentation for android shell commands in /system/bin and in system/xbin?

Tags: android, shell

Where can I find documentation for android shell commands in /system/bin and in system/xbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have collected some of the major `adb commands`

Here is a collection of adb commands

> 1 Navigate To Home Screen  -->  "adb shell am start -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME"
>
> 2 Application Install  -->  "adb install TPLTRCU.apk"
>
> 3 Application Uninstall   -->  "adb uninstall com.tpltrcu"
>
> 4 To view apk properties  -->  "aapt dump badging "
>
> 5 To Remove the Default Launcher   -->  "adb shell rm
>   /system/app/Launcher3.apk"
>
> 6 Android Running Services  -->  "adb shell dumpsys activity services"
>
> 7 Android Version  -->  "adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release"
>
> 8 Android SDK Version  -->  "adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>
> 9 Android properties  --> "adb shell getprop"
>
> 10 Date & Time  -->  "adb shell date"
>
> 11 Application Force-Stop  -->  "adb shell am force-stop "
>
> 12 Running Processes  -->  "adb shell ps"
>
> 13 ADB shell   -->  "adb shell"
>
> 14 Network status  -->  "adb shell netcfg"
>
> 15 To get a file  -->  "adb pull path_to_file"
>
> 16 To put a file  -->  "adb push sourcePath destinationPath"
>
> 17 To Change time Zone  -->  "adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone
>   "Asia/Kolkata""
>           To find Time-Zone [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones]
>
> 18 To take backups  -->  “adb backup -apk -shared -all”
>
> 19 To Restore  -->  “adb restore backup.ab”
>
> 20 To save logs from android   -->  “adb shell logcat > log.txt”
>
> 21 To check CPU usage  -->  “adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo”
>
> 22 To CheckMemory usage  -->  “adb shell dumpsys meminfo”
>
> 23 To Change Settings  -->  “adb shell am start -n
>   com.android.settings/.Settings”
>
> 24 Bug Report Via ADB  -->  “adb bugreport > bug_report.txt”
>
> 25 Bug Report Parsing  -->  “java -jar chkbugreport.jar
>   bug_report.txt”
>           To get chkbugreport.jar [https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/ChkBugReport/downloads]
>
> 26 To Reboot the OS  -->  "adb shell reboot"
>
> 27 ADB Version  -->  "adb version"
>
> 28 To get Help  -->  "adb help"
>
> 29 To get Serial Number   -->  "adb get-serialno"
>
> 30 List of devices  -->  "adb devices"
>
> 31 To get running process  -->  "adb shell ps"
>
> 32 To print dump  -->  "adb shell dumpsys"
>
> 33 To start an Activity  -->  "adb shell am start
>   PACKAGE_NAME/.ACTIVITY_NAME"
>
> 34 To save screenshot  -->  "adb shell screencap -p
>   /mnt/image_name.png"
>
> 35 List of installed packages  -->  "adb shell pm list packages -f"
>
> 36    To make key event   -->  "adb shell input keyevent"
>
> Logcat Options
>
> If you want to control the format of each log entry is dumped, you
>   need to use the "adb logcat -v " option, which supports the
>   following formats:
>
> 37    Display priority/tag and the PID of process issuing the message
>   (the default format)  -->  "adb logcat -v     brief"
>
> 38    Display PID only  -->  "adb logcat -v process"
>
> 39    Display the priority/tag only   -->  "adb logcat -v tag"
>
> 40    Display the raw log message, with no other metadata fields  --> 
>   "adb logcat -v raw"
>
> 41    Display the date, invocation time, priority/tag, and PID of the
>   process issuing the message  -->  "adb logcat -v time"
>
> 42    Display the priority, tag, and the PID and TID of the thread
>   issuing the message  -->  "adb logcat -v thread"
>
> 43    Display the date, invocation time, priority, tag, and the PID
>   and TID of the thread issuing the message     -->"adb logcat -v
>   threadtime"
>
> 44   Display all metadata fields and separate messages with a blank
>   lines  -->  "adb logcat -v long"
>
> Key codes for adb command "input keyevent"
>
> 0 -->  "KEYCODE_UNKNOWN"
>
> 1 -->  "KEYCODE_MENU"
>
> 2 -->  "KEYCODE_SOFT_RIGHT"
>
> 3 -->  "KEYCODE_HOME"
>
> 4 -->  "KEYCODE_BACK"
>
> 5 -->  "KEYCODE_CALL"
>
> 6 -->  "KEYCODE_ENDCALL"
>
> 7 -->  "KEYCODE_0"
>
> 8 -->  "KEYCODE_1"
>
> 9 -->  "KEYCODE_2"
>
> 10 -->  "KEYCODE_3"
>
> 11 -->  "KEYCODE_4"
>
> 12 -->  "KEYCODE_5"
>
> 13 -->  "KEYCODE_6"
>
> 14 -->  "KEYCODE_7"
>
> 15 -->  "KEYCODE_8"
>
> 16 -->  "KEYCODE_9"
>
> 17 -->  "KEYCODE_STAR"
>
> 18 -->  "KEYCODE_POUND"
>
> 19 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_UP"
>
> 20 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN"
>
> 21 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT"
>
> 22 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT"
>
> 23 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER"
>
> 24 -->  "KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP"
>
> 25 -->  "KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN"
>
> 26 -->  "KEYCODE_POWER"
>
> 27 -->  "KEYCODE_CAMERA"
>
> 28 -->  "KEYCODE_CLEAR"
>
> 29 -->  "KEYCODE_A"
>
> 30 -->  "KEYCODE_B"
>
> 31 -->  "KEYCODE_C"
>
> 32 -->  "KEYCODE_D"
>
> 33 -->  "KEYCODE_E"
>
> 34 -->  "KEYCODE_F"
>
> 35 -->  "KEYCODE_G"
>
> 36 -->  "KEYCODE_H"
>
> 37 -->  "KEYCODE_I"
>
> 38 -->  "KEYCODE_J"
>
> 39 -->  "KEYCODE_K"
>
> 40 -->  "KEYCODE_L"
>
> 41 -->  "KEYCODE_M"
>
> 42 -->  "KEYCODE_N"
>
> 43 -->  "KEYCODE_O"
>
> 44 -->  "KEYCODE_P"
>
> 45 -->  "KEYCODE_Q"
>
> 46 -->  "KEYCODE_R"
>
> 47 -->  "KEYCODE_S"
>
> 48 -->  "KEYCODE_T"
>
> 49 -->  "KEYCODE_U"
>
> 50 -->  "KEYCODE_V"
>
> 51 -->  "KEYCODE_W"
>
> 52 -->  "KEYCODE_X"
>
> 53 -->  "KEYCODE_Y"
>
> 54 -->  "KEYCODE_Z"
>
> 55 -->  "KEYCODE_COMMA"
>
> 56 -->  "KEYCODE_PERIOD"
>
> 57 -->  "KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT"
>
> 58 -->  "KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT"
>
> 59 -->  "KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT"
>
> 60 -->  "KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT"
>
> 61 -->  "KEYCODE_TAB"
>
> 62 -->  "KEYCODE_SPACE"
>
> 63 -->  "KEYCODE_SYM"
>
> 64 -->  "KEYCODE_EXPLORER"
>
> 65 -->  "KEYCODE_ENVELOPE"
>
> 66 -->  "KEYCODE_ENTER"
>
> 67 -->  "KEYCODE_DEL"
>
> 68 -->  "KEYCODE_GRAVE"
>
> 69 -->  "KEYCODE_MINUS"
>
> 70 -->  "KEYCODE_EQUALS"
>
> 71 -->  "KEYCODE_LEFT_BRACKET"
>
> 72 -->  "KEYCODE_RIGHT_BRACKET"
>
> 73 -->  "KEYCODE_BACKSLASH"
>
> 74 -->  "KEYCODE_SEMICOLON"
>
> 75 -->  "KEYCODE_APOSTROPHE"
>
> 76 -->  "KEYCODE_SLASH"
>
> 77 -->  "KEYCODE_AT"
>
> 78 -->  "KEYCODE_NUM"
>
> 79 -->  "KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK"
>
> 80 -->  "KEYCODE_FOCUS"
>
> 81 -->  "KEYCODE_PLUS"
>
> 82 -->  "KEYCODE_MENU"
>
> 83 -->  "KEYCODE_NOTIFICATION"
>
> 84 -->  "KEYCODE_SEARCH"
>
> 85 -->  "TAG_LAST_KEYCODE"

The complete guide

> Embedded Android by Karim Yaghmour

will also help you . You can [buy it from here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do?sortby=publicationDate) . For [E-Book follow](http://kysmykseka.net/koti/wizardry/The%20Actually%20Useful%20Programming%20Library/Android/Embedded%20Android%20-%20Yaghmour%20-%20O'Reilly%20(2011).pdf) this

Comment: Im in China Since the Great Fire Wall,I can not open your doc link(http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/2014/10/adb-commands.html),is there another link?Or can you send the doc to my email zhutiantao@baidu.com thx.